# Whats wrong with my Javascript Date Comparison

Tags: javascript, date, comparison

Im tyring to compare two dates in javascript but im getting strange values when calculating the dates.

Can anyone see anything obvious in my code that is causing the issue?

The problem is the Todays date variable looks like a normal date, but my calculation for next week and last week are coming out as large numbers and the comparison wont work.

```
//Handles client side date selection changed
function dateSelectionChanged(sender, args) {

    //Declare array for Day names
    var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

    //Get the date
    var date = sender.get_selectedDate();

    //Get todays Date
    var today = new Date();
    var nextWeek = new Date().setDate(today.getDate() + 7);
    var lastWeek = new Date().setDate(today.getDate() - 7);

    //Show the day name
    $('#<%= txtDay.ClientID %>').val(days[date.getDay()]);

    if ( date < lastWeek ) {
        alert('Date Under Week');
    }
    if ( date > nextWeek ) {
        alert('Date Over Week');
    }
}
```

And here is the Code in Debug so you can see the values:
[image]

**EDIT:**
Solution

```
//Handles client side date selection changed
function dateSelectionChanged(sender, args) {

    //Declare array for Day names
    var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

    //Get the date
    var date = sender.get_selectedDate();

    //Get todays Date
    var today = new Date();
    var nextWeek = new Date().setDate(today.getDate() + 7);
    var lastWeek = new Date().setDate(today.getDate() - 7);

    //Get the dates in easier to compare format
    nextWeek = new Date(nextWeek);
    lastWeek = new Date(lastWeek);

    //Show the day name
    $('#<%= txtDay.ClientID %>').val(days[date.getDay()]);

    if ( date < lastWeek) {
        alert('Date Under Week');
    }
    if ( date > nextWeek) {
        alert('Date Over Week');
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The large numbers you obtain?

Comment: Just a comment, since this isn't really a full answer. the other way you could have done it would be to coerce `today` to be a number. This is actually very simple: `today = +(new Date());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `setDate`, JavaScript returns timestamps, which represent the amount of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 to a specific moment in time. It might look useless, but in fact is very useful as you can represent any time as a simple number.

In case you want to get back a `Date`, you can use:

```
new Date(timestamp);
```

so e.g. add:

```
nextWeek = new Date(nextWeek);
lastWeek = new Date(lastWeek);
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like its sorted the problem. Doesnt help that I was comparing todays date with next week and last week rather than the selected date also!

Comment: @WraithNath: Oops, I didn't see that. You probably want `date.setDate` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to set dates like this.

```
var today = new Date();
var nextWeek = new Date();
nextWeek.setDate(today.getDate() + 7);
var lastWeek = new Date();
lastWeek.setDate(today.getDate() - 7);
```

Answer (score -1):

> If you supply no arguments, the constructor creates a Date object for
>   today's date and time according to local time. If you supply some
>   arguments but not others, the missing arguments are set to 0. If you
>   supply any arguments, you must supply at least the year, month, and
>   day. You can omit the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds.
>
> The date is measured in milliseconds since midnight 01 January, 1970
>   UTC.
>   A day holds 86,400,000 milliseconds. The Date object range is
>   -100,000,000 days to 100,000,000 days relative to 01 January, 1970
>   UTC.

try the following code while comparing the dates

```
if ( today < lastWeek.getMilliseconds() ) {
        alert('Date Under Week');
    }
    if ( today > nextWeek.getMilliseconds() ) {
        alert('Date Over Week');
    }
```

> The Date object provides uniform behavior across platforms.

Comment: Thanks, just realised I was also comparing Todays date with last week and next week, which will never work! Updated the code to use the selected date.

Comment: Since `lastWeek` and `nextWeek` are numbers those functions are not available. Moreover it returns the milliseconds within one second, so it's not extremely useful, and they are the same in this case as only the date number has been changed.

Comment: Did you chose `getMilliseconds` at random?